# Python - stop WSGI application after specific request

Tags: python, multithreading, wsgi

I need to create an application that ends after receiving a specific request. I use `wsgiref.simple_server` and run handling request in separate thread.
There is my code:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import re
import threading
import urllib2

def webapp(environ, start_response):
    path = environ.get('PATH_INFO', '').lstrip('/')
    for regex, callback in urls:
        match = re.search(regex, path)
        if match is not None:
            environ['app.url_args'] = match.groups()
            return callback(environ, start_response)
    return not_found(environ, start_response)

KEEP_RUNNING = True
srv = make_server('localhost', 8081, webapp)

def t_serve():
    while KEEP_RUNNING:
        srv.handle_request()

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=t_serve)
    t.start()
    print 'Service is running.'
    t.join()

def index(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ['Service works']

def t_stop_service():
    print 'Service shutdown'
    urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:8081/')

def stop_service(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    global KEEP_RUNNING
    KEEP_RUNNING = False
    threading.Thread(target=t_stop_service).start()
    return ['Service is stopping']

def not_found(environ, start_response):
    """Called if no URL matches."""
    start_response('404 NOT FOUND', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ['<h1>Not Found</h1>']

urls = [
    (r'^$', index),
    (r'^stop/?$', stop_service)
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After I make request "stop" request processing ends, but the process of the program is not ending. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the WSGI server whether it will work, with good quality ones it usually doesn't for good reasons, but have you tried using `sys.exit()` from the request handler?

If you must, you could also use `os._exit(1)`. This will cause Python to exit immediately, although it will not allow any cleanup code to run.